# Free libary in C# for inking on a PDF

Tags: open-source, pdf, c#

I am looking for a truly free (open source) PDF libary for c# with would enable me to annoate a PDF with a stylus.

Comment: Are you looking for an application or a library? If you're looking for a library, do you want it to just be able to annotate the PDF, or also to provide UI elements for displaying the PDF, which accepts the stylus input? If you also want the UI element, what UI platform (WPF, Winforms, UWP, Xamarin, …) are you using?

Comment: @svick UI yes, Winforms

Answer (score 1):

You can use **iTextSharp** which is available in an open-source version, in combination with the **System.Windows.Input.Stylus** or **System.Windows.Ink** class. It is widely supported and has many APIs for inking and PDF creation.

Comment: okay. Thanks a lot. I am a beginner, so would you mind to tell me if you know of any tutorials or demos which show how to do it ?

Comment: @DoHe For using System.Windows.Input.Stylus, you can check out its appropriate documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.stylus(v=vs.110).aspx. For a tutorial on this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752334(v=vs.110).aspx. For iTextSharp, you can check out one of many YouTube videos. Here's a useful one: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MyhLW84cWrY.

Comment: @CoputersAreCool Thanks a lot !! This really helps. Do you know, if it is also possible to implement Will Universal Ink from Wacom instead of the windows solution ?

Answer (score 0):

[Syncfusion Essential PDF Viewer for WPF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/pdf-viewer) is an option to consider. [Here](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/175121/ze/PdfViewerWPF2070523934) is a sample application.

[image: Syncfusion PDF Annotations]

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense?refer=screcs40064) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This looks great !  Do you know, if it is also possible to implement Will Universal Ink from Wacom ?

Comment: @DoHe We have analyzed Wacom’s WILL Universal Ink and they have provided SDKs for native iOS, native Android and  WinRT. What platform do you need this for?

Comment: @DoHe Wacom developer site only has SDKs for WinRT. For Windows 10, we would need a .NET or UWP SDK. Do you know if they provide those?

Comment: No, I am afraid, I don't know

Comment: @DoHe We have made contact with Wacom and they have confirmed that a new developer program with expanded set of SDKs will be available and we will be able to support WILL on Windows 10 at that point.

Comment: Thank you very much for contacting them ! Did they tell you when it will be available ?

Comment: @DoHe They didn't provide a date, but I am still in touch with them and will update here when they provide a date.